# Codeigniter - make email unreadable by bots

Tags: codeigniter, security, email, bots

Is there a method in codeigniter to make email links unreadable by bots? If not does anyone recommend a decent simple solution?

Comment: Use a helper function to use html encoded charaters for charaters in the email address.

Comment: which helper is that? can't see it in the email helper

Comment: No I was suggesting to extend the email helper and add this function to change the normal characters to html encoded charater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops..

Codeigniter has a function safe_mailto() in the URL helper

Answer (score 0):

I was told this will work for google search appliance

```
<!--googleoff: index-->
<a href="mailto:abc@stackoverflow.com">my email</a>
<!--googleon: index-->
```

Source: http://perishablepress.com/tell-google-to-not-index-certain-parts-of-your-page/

Please let me know if is incorrect.

Comment: This method doesn't protect you from anything. Bot's don't require google to pickup emails.

Answer (score 0):

There probably isn't any perfect solution here, especially if you don't want to inconvenience your users.

One simple method (which could be combined with the google comments mentioned by ajreal), would be to use entity encoding to obfuscate their source. This would block simple bots.

See here for some details: http://www.wbwip.com/wbw/emailencoder.html

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter has a safe_mailto() method in the URL Helper class that obfuscates e-mail addresses in the HTML source code, without affecting the end user.

https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/url_helper.html#safe_mailto

Example Template Code:

```
<p>My e-mail address is <?php $this->load->helper('url'); echo safe_mailto('abc@gmail.com'); ?>.</p>
```

Example HTML Output:

```
<p>My e-mail address is <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var l=new Array();
l[0] = '>';
l[1] = 'a';
l[2] = '/';
l[3] = '<';
l[4] = '|109';
l[5] = '|111';
l[6] = '|99';
l[7] = '|46';
l[8] = '|108';
l[9] = '|105';
l[10] = '|97';
l[11] = '|109';
l[12] = '|103';
l[13] = '|64';
l[14] = '|99';
l[15] = '|98';
l[16] = '|97';
l[17] = '>';
l[18] = '"';
l[19] = '|109';
l[20] = '|111';
l[21] = '|99';
l[22] = '|46';
l[23] = '|108';
l[24] = '|105';
l[25] = '|97';
l[26] = '|109';
l[27] = '|103';
l[28] = '|64';
l[29] = '|99';
l[30] = '|98';
l[31] = '|97';
l[32] = ':';
l[33] = 'o';
l[34] = 't';
l[35] = 'l';
l[36] = 'i';
l[37] = 'a';
l[38] = 'm';
l[39] = '"';
l[40] = '=';
l[41] = 'f';
l[42] = 'e';
l[43] = 'r';
l[44] = 'h';
l[45] = ' ';
l[46] = 'a';
l[47] = '<';

for (var i = l.length-1; i >= 0; i=i-1) {
    if (l[i].substring(0, 1) === '|') document.write("&#"+unescape(l[i].substring(1))+";");
    else document.write(unescape(l[i]));
}
//]]>
</script>.</p>
```